# Proving limits by definition (2 variables)

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I need to prove with the formal limit definition ( epsilon and delta)

1. $\lim_{(x,y)\to(-1,8)} xy = -8$ and
2. $\lim_{(x,y)\to(2,3)} y\sin(xy-6)=0$

I've been trying to solve them all day, but can't figure out what to do.

Comment: Is this really what you meant to ask, or did I mess up your formulas somehow?  The first limit is evidently -2, not -8.

Comment: I need to prove them with epsilon and delta. Just corrected my error. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Note that these are continuous function, so in order to compute them you can just substitute the values.

Comment: Need to prove it using the formal definition with epsilon and delta.